# How can I disable the multitouch functionality of a touchscreen?

Tags: touchscreen, multi-touch, xinput

I have an 7 inch touchscreen, I've only configured it through the xinput calibrator and it works perfectly. However, I want to use it as an interface for an application I'm running via Chromium, and I don't want the functions multi-touch makes possible to be available. Is there any way to configure the screen in a way that turns it into a single-touch only device? I've looked and it really doesn't look like it can be done with just browser settings.

Be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Go to a terminal by Pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and enter the following command: `synclient` and if it produces any valuable output, please [edit] your question, provide the output there and then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: @Oz-Fern  Did you figure it out?